# "Infinite Drill-down" with UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

Can anyone suggest an article or perhaps an example of how to create an "infinite drill-down" with UINavigationController like you see in the Facebook, IMDB and BrightKite apps?

Comment: could you be more specific on what you like on Facebook, IMDB, and BrightKite?  I was on IMDB site and didn't see what you were referring to.

Comment: Each of these iPhone apps have at least one navigation controller that allows you to infinitely drill-down through content.  Example: In IMDB, you can search for an actor, open their view, open a film of theirs, then open a different actor, then a different film, etc. etc.  The app is obviously tracking history somehow and automatically popping off views beyond a certain point... otherwise it would crash from exceeding the memory limits of the watchdog.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never having done this...  I would approach this by keeping a stack with a light-weight object containing the contents of the previous view (perhaps just a URL?).  Rather than just push on a new UIViewController to the UINavigationController, you would pop your current one, without animation, then push on the new view.  However, I don't think this would properly handle the nice animation.

Another way that comes to mind would be to manipulation the viewControllers array of UINavigationController.  After pushing on a new view, just remove the previous view from the array.  That way the UINavigationController stack would only ever be 1 or two elements deep.  Handling the back button would create the proper view, insert it into the viewControllers array, then pop off the current one.  Your state would be managed by the lightweight object stack, not heavyweight view controllers.

-dan

Comment: I'm currently looking into using Three20's TTNavigator as a solution, as it appears to support this functionality... though the documentation is terrible so I'm not sure yet.

Answer (score 4):

The `UINavigationController` is designed to be used this way. If memory becomes an issue, the nav controller will release hidden views and reload them when the time comes to navigate back down the stack. Apple recommends you load your `UIView`s from a NIB for this reason.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH103-SW28

Scroll down to item #4, "Configure the view for your root view controller."

Comment: kubi,  Thanks for the tip.  Have you tried this?  You could put a log in viewDidUnload (or isn't this called?).

-dan

Comment: Based on my experiments, this is not true.  UINavigationController does not appear to automatically remove any views from the stack, except when you are navigating back.

Comment: @Daniel actually no, but i've also not had memory issues when using NavControllers this way, so I assumed everything was working like the documents described. Please let me now if you find differently.

Comment: Broken link - do you know what has replaced it?

Comment: I don't know what has replaced, but unloading view controllers hasn't been part of iOS for years now, so my answer is a bit outdated.